# How do i stop full line highlight in vs code versions control?

Tags: visual-studio-code, line, highlight

Is there any way to stop the full line highlight in versions control?
It is very confusing when the vscode is highlighting the full line and not only the changed piece of code especially when there is a lot of changes.
[vscode vs sublime merge line highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDeCr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some related issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116413
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103207
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66223

Upvote these - especially the first which is in the candidate phase.

You can play around with these `colorCustomizations` in your settings.jsonwhich might help a "little":

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "diffEditor.insertedTextBorder": "#0f0",
  "diffEditor.insertedTextBackground": "#0000",  // set to transparent
  "diffEditor.removedTextBackground": "#0000",   // set to transparent
  "diffEditor.removedTextBorder": "#f00"
}
```

But these changes don't help much in my opinion.  Upvoting is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for the temporary solution! I will definitely upvote the feature request.